# send mail via python with SMTP server

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

i tried to send mail via win server with python script (i used 2.7 ver)

in the server i have a program that already send me mails and its working....

the address that send me mail is :

**YYY@test.co.il**

now i try to send mail to this addrres(xxx@) via this sscript :

```
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage
with open(textfile) as fp:
    # Create a text/plain message
    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg.set_content(fp.read())

msg['test'] = f'The contents of {textfile}'
msg['From'] = YYY@test.co.il
msg['To'] = xxx@test.co.il

# Send the message via our own SMTP server.
s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
s.send_message(msg)
s.quit()
```

i got this line error :
`msg['test'] = f'The contents of {textfile}'`

there an error in your program invalid syntax

whats i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

An effective workaround is :

```
msg['test'] = 'The contents of' + str(textfile)
```